# Special ORDER BY with CASE statement - In need of guidance

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, case

I am thinking about how I need to write this query. I think it may involve having a CASE in the ORDER BY Statement but I could use a little guidance.

I have two columns of data; ID and price. When I ORDER BY Price ASC, my query results display something like this:

> ID | Price 
>  3 | 150 
>  1 | 200 
>  3 | 205 
>  2 | 210 
>  2 | 230 
>  3 | 270 
>  1 | 300 
>  2 | 340 
>  3 | 500

What I am looking to do is to still ORDER by Price ASC but with a slight variation. I want to group by IDs as well. For example, I would like the query to find the lowest price of all results and then find all other records that have the same ID, listed in price ASC order. Once all records for that ID had been found, the query would then look to all other remaining records, find the lowest price again, and repeat. So there would be decreasing pool of results each time it went through this loop. For the above example, the result would be:

> ID | Price 
>  3 | 150 
>  3 | 205 
>  3 | 270 
>  3 | 500 
>  1 | 200  
>  1 | 300 
>  2 | 210 
>  2 | 230   
>  2 | 340

The loop is something like find lowest price, find all records with the same ID and list in price order, find lowest price of remaining results, find all records with the same ID and list in price order, repeat....

Any Ideas? Let me know if I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: You'd need to do something like, ORDER BY and then order by a sub query/temporary table that has ordered the IDs by their minimum price and produced a column that ranks them from 1 to N. And then you can just associate your row's ID with that subquery/temp table's index, ordering by that will give you the order you desire. And then you can have a secondary ordering (as in order by x, y) to sub-order by price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Postgres, so you have the window functions.  Here is an example of the SQL you need:

```
select id, price
from (select t.*,
             min(price) over (partition by id) as minprice
      from t
     ) t
order by minprice, id, price
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT ID, PRICE
FROM t
ORDER BY MIN(PRICE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID), PRICE
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5141a/4)

Comment: Yeah, I like this option as well. Very straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5141a/1)

```
select t.id, t.price
from
    t
    inner
    join (
        select row_number() over(order by price) o, id
        from (
            select id, min(price) price
            from t
            group by id
        ) s
    ) s on s.id = t.id
order by s.o, t.price
```